# Comparison of Join and WaitAll

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

For multiple threads wait, can anyone compare the pros and cons of using `WaitHandle.WaitAll` and `Thread.Join`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WaitHandle.WaitAll` has a 64 handle limit so that is obviously a huge limitation. On the other hand, it is a convenient way to wait for many signals in only a single call. `Thread.Join` does not require creating any additional `WaitHandle` instances. And since it could be called individually on each thread the 64 handle limit does not apply.

Personally, I have never used `WaitHandle.WaitAll`. I prefer a more scalable pattern when I want to wait on multiple signals. You can create a counting mechanism that counts up or down and once a specific value is reach you signal a single shared event. The `CountdownEvent` class conveniently packages all of this into a single class.

```
var finished = new CountdownEvent(1);
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_WORK_ITEMS; i++)
{
  finished.AddCount();
  SpawnAsynchronousOperation(
    () =>
    {
      try
      {
        // Place logic to run in parallel here.
      }
      finally
      {
        finished.Signal();
      }
    }
}
finished.Signal();
finished.Wait();
```

**Update:**

The reason why you want to signal the event from the main thread is subtle. Basically, you want to treat the main thread as if it were just another work item. Afterall, it, along with the other *real* work items, is running concurrently as well.

Consider for a moment what might happen if we did not treat the main thread as a work item. It will go through one iteration of the `for` loop and add a count to our event (via `AddCount`) indicating that we have one pending work item right? Lets say the `SpawnAsynchronousOperation` completes and gets the work item queued on another thread. Now, imagine if the main thread gets preempted before swinging around to the next iteration of the loop. The thread executing the work item gets its fair share of the CPU and starts humming along and actually completes the work item. The `Signal` call in the work item runs and decrements our pending work item count to zero which will change the state of the `CountdownEvent` to signalled. In the meantime the main thread wakes up and goes through all iterations of the loop and hits the `Wait` call, but since the event got prematurely signalled it pass on by even though there are still pending work items.

Again, avoiding this subtle race condition is easy when you treat the main thread as a work item. That is why the `CountdownEvent` is intialized with one count and the `Signal` method is called before the `Wait`.

Comment: @Pieter: Great question! I updated my answer with a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I like @Brian's answer as a comparison of the two mechanisms.

If you are on .Net 4, it would be worthwhile exploring [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) to achieve Task Parellelism via [System.Threading.Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.aspx) which allows you to manage tasks across multiple threads at a higher level of abstraction.  The signalling you asked about in this question to manage thread interactions is hidden or much simplified, and you can concentrate on properly defining what each Task consists of and how to coordinate them.

This may seem offtopic but as Microsoft themselves say in the MSDN docs:

> in the .NET Framework 4, tasks are the
>   preferred API for writing
>   multi-threaded, asynchronous, and
>   parallel code.

Answer (score 0):

The waitall mechanism involves kernal-mode objects.  I don't think the same is true for the join mechanism.  I would prefer join, given the opportunity.

Technically though, the two are not equivalent.  IIRC `Join` can only operate on one thread.  `Waitall` can hold for the signalling of multiple kernel objects.